# Javascript, PHP json will not parse?

Tags: php, javascript, json

I am sending this to PHP:

```
  {'command' : 'move', 'data' : { 'seat_id' : '"+seat+"'}}
```

But cannot parse it though PHP. The correct data i got from PHP is:

```
 {'command' : 'move', 'data' : { 'seat_id' : '44'}}
```

I have tried following:

```
 <?php
 $in = $Server->output(); //this is the json text
 $o = json_decode($in); //has also tried put "TRUE" in the function.
 print_r($o); ?>
```

It just output

```
 {'command' : 'move', 'data' : { 'seat_id' : '44'}}
```

Comment: Proper JSON uses double quotes, not single quotes.

Comment: Oh, thanks, LOL. Post as answer.

Comment: How are you creating that string? Various JS libraries will do the encoding to JSON for you.

Answer (score 3):

Proper JSON uses double quotes, not single quotes.